# How to retrieve second item of HashSet<Tuple<string, int>>

Tags: c#, .net

I've a  `HashSet<Tuple<string, int>>` In the second item I've numbers (1,18,5,46).

I'd like to get biggest number of in these items.

I'm new in programming so please forgive me for question.

I've just found a way and want to share:
`int max = students.Max(kvp => kvp.Item2);`

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code!?

Comment: I'm adding to HashSet<Tuple> first item studentname and for second item  studentexamresults.  `students.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(studentName[i], studentExamResult[i))`

Comment: Why would you use a `HashSet` for this? `HashSet`s perform very good when you do simple lookups. But if you have to iterate over all items you could simply use a `List<T>`.

Comment: Because I need unique values. And I've just solved I don't know is it good or bad solution. `int max = students.Max(kvp => kvp.Item2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var students = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

        students.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("test", 10));
        students.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("test", 10));

        Console.Write(students.Max(t => t.Item2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.I've done like that. `int max = students.Max(kvp => kvp.Item2);`  Which way has better performance?

Comment: @AlbertoCubas I believe your way uses a little less heap space in higher scales.

Comment: @AlbertoCubas I like your solution.

Comment: Thanks mate, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: @AlbertoCubas could you upvote to balance the downvote I've got?

Comment: @kblok OP needs at least 15 reps to be able to upvote.

Comment: @ModusTollens oh yup that's true

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. 
:(